# Constraint on class

Tags: c#, constraints

Trying to define constraint on class, but get error:

```
public class Utilities3<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public T Max<T>(T a, T b) 
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
    }
}
```

> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'CompareTo' and no extension method 'CompareTo' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Cannot resolve symbol 'CompareTo'

[image: error]

While constraint on function works fine:

```
public class Utilities2<T>
{
    public T Max<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparable
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
    }
}
```

Why constraint on class not working?

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of the error, you could post its text, so this question could be easily found using the search machines.

Comment: The issue is that you've redefined `T` on the method and that hides the `T` defined on the class.

Comment: Remove the `<T>` from `Max`, as `T` is already defined on the generic class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code:

```
public T Max<T>(T a, T b)
```

Defines a new < T> constraint which overwrites the one that you use for the class. Remove this < T> in method and you'll be using a class constraint instead

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that you've redefined `T` on the method and that hides the `T` defined on the class.  So you either need the constraint on the method or more likely you shouldn't redefine the generic type.

```
public class Utilities3<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public T Max(T a, T b) 
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
    }
}
```

You typically only define generic types on either a class or it's methods. And if for some reason you do need to define them in both places it would be better to give them unique names unless you specifically want the hiding behavior, but that's very unlikely.

Comment: Most likely OP should remove constraint from class and leave on method, because who would want to do `Utilities3<int>.Max(a, b)` instead of just `Utilities3.Max(a,b)`.

Comment: @Evk `Max` is not `static` that's why.  Now maybe it should be `static`, but that's really outside of the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to define the generics at the method level and not the class level. For example:

```
public class Utilities
{
    public T Max<T>(T a, T b) where T : IComparable
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b)>0 ? a : b;
    }
    public bool Equals<T>(T a, T b) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        return a!=null ? a.Equals(b) : b==null;
    }
}
```

This allows setting the type constraints per the method instead of trying to capture all of them with `class Utilties  where T : IComparable, IEquatable<T>, ...`